# How can I make sure users follow specific naming conventions for new items added to lists and libraries?

Tags: sharepoint-online

One way I discovered was that we can type a formula in validation settings for a list or library. For Example : `[File Name]=[Title]&"-"&[Analyst Name] ,` which produces a file name such as **MerchantDetails-Abhishek** !

But again the problem here is that this doesn't works for look-up columns. I am just a beginner in SharePoint, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot use lookup fields in Column validation in OOTB** in formula.

You will have to use the client object model(JavaScript, jQuery), or item adding event receiver (custom code) for column validation.